# apps.groups.migration return HTTP error 500

Tags: google-groups-migration

I am trying to import existing mail content to a google group through apps.groups.migration API. The code is in C++ and the protolol is nakid HTTP. The program fails with HTTP error 500.

Following is the error response contents and header. What is wrong ?

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
```

{
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "backendError",
    "message": "Backend Error"
   }
  ],
  "code": 500,
  "message": "Backend Error"
     }
    }

Alternate-Protocol: 443:quic
Content-Length: 177
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Thu, 02 Jan 2014 06:50:10 GMT
Server: HTTP Upload Server Built on Dec 11 2013 18:21:10 (1386814870)

Comment: I quoted the HTTP request with Sleep(1000)s and add 10 times retry but the error 500 still occurs. The error is 500, not 503.

Comment: I am trying to put data into Google Groups, not Google Groups for Business. Is it the reason of error 500 ?
The reason why I am using Nakid HTTP is:
I am using Windows, not Linux or MacOS. The code base is from my working applications with Google Calendar API or Google Tasks API.

Answer (score 0):

Backend Errors are a normal part of working with Google APIs and generally indicate that your application is sending data to Google to fast and needs to backoff some. See the details in the [Group Migration API Limits document](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/groups-migration/v1/limits). Further details about implementing exponential backoff are offered in the [Drive API docs](https://developers.google.com/drive/handle-errors#implementing_exponential_backoff).

You may want to take a look at the [Google APIs Client Library for C++](http://google.github.io/google-api-cpp-client/latest/) rather than reinventing the wheel for these interactions.